# Как задать значение глобальной переменной в зависимости от подключённых заголовков?

Tags: c++, c, global-variables, препроцессор

Необходимо проинициализировать переменную в директиве препроцессора до её использования в программе с учётом подключённых модулей. Если подключен первый модуль, то у переменной будет одно значение, если подключен второй модуль - у неё будет другое значение. Есть такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "FirstClass.h"
using namespace std;

string PARAM;

#ifdef __FIRSTCLASS__H
    PARAM = "first";

#elif __SECONDCLASS__H
    PARAM = "second";

#endif

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << PARAM << endl;
}
```

Однако, он не работает. Переменная так и остаётся пустой. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём ошибка, и как её исправить?

Comment: Вы делаете что-то не то. А какое значение будет иметь переменная, если подключены оба модуля? А если ни один? Расскажите лучше свою настоящую задачу, скорее всего, вы решаете её неправильно.

Comment: @VladD, не будет такой ситуации, когда оба. Это и есть настоящая задача.

Comment: Не, не может быть. Вы решаете задачу на уровне чистого _синтаксиса_ (подключен  header => автоматически происходит что-то), а нужно на уровне _семантики_ (модуль должен иметь специальную репрезентацию в коде).

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что у Вас при компиляции не определены ни `__FIRSTCLASS__H`, ни `__SECONDCLASS__H` (иначе этот код просто не скомпилируется).

Предлагаю писать что-то в таком роде:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string param 
#ifdef _ONE
  = "first"
#elif _TWO
  = "second"
#endif
  ;

int main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  cout << "param = " << param << '\n';
}
```

Использование:

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ c.cpp -D_ONE
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out
param = first
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ c.cpp -D_TWO
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out
param = second
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ c.cpp -D_TW
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out
param =
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Такая инициализация переменной "param" связана с тем, что глобальные переменные нельзя оставлять непроинициализированными?

Comment: всё равно переменная пустая.

Comment: Глобальные переменные можно оставлять непроинициализированными. Но в глобальной области нельзя присваивать значения, за исключением инициализации. Т.к. это не имеет никакого смысла. Переменная у Вас пустая, потому что ни `__FIRSTCLASS__H` ни `__SECONDCLASS__H` не заданы. Напишите сразу после `using namespace std:` `#define __FIRSTCLASS__H` и сразу станет не пустая строка

Comment: В принципе оставлять неинициализируемыми можно (см. `g++ c.cpp -D_TW` в примере), но наверное, нехорошо. Если все равно пустая, значит по прежнему переменные в `#ifdef` не определены. Проверьте свой код (включая код в `#include`) получше.

Answer (score 1):

Если вас устраивает присваивать в месте объявления переменной, тогда так

```
string PARAM
#ifdef __FIRSTCLASS__H
  = "first"
#elif __SECONDCLASS__H
  = "second"
#endif
;
```

Если вы хотите присваивать в любом месте, то используйте макрос, вместо переменной, либо это:

```
struct Initializer
{
    Initializer()
    {
#ifdef __FIRSTCLASS__H
        PARAM = "first";

#elif __SECONDCLASS__H
       PARAM = "second";
#else
    }
};
Initializer initializer;
```

Answer (score 0):

я бы написал код так

```
#ifdef __FIRSTCLASS__H
    PARAM = "first";

#elif __SECONDCLASS__H
    PARAM = "second";
#else
  #error "include some file!"
#endif
```

Скорее всего ругнется. А ругнется, потому что в FirstClass.h объявляется другое. Или вообще используется include once.

p.s. Но код возможно придется переместить в правильное место:)

Comment: Так вообще нельзя присваивать, в глобальном пространстве видимости.

Comment: А где в моем коде глобальное пространство видимости?

Comment: В коде вопроса глобальное пространство, в Вашем ответе немного поправленный код из вопроса. Логика подсказывает, что пространство не изменилось.

Comment: автор утверждает, что его код компилируется, но не работает правильно. Поэтому мой кусок кода должен ему помочь. Вполне возможно, что он пропустил пару строк кода.

Comment: да, скорее всего у автора не задано ни одно из двух определений, поэтому и компилируется. Как только исправит, все сломается.